# Add Two Background Images to the Body With JQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to add two separate background images to the body tag using JQuery. Initially this was achieved with the following class:

```
.background: url(../img/ad-takeoverbkg-left.jpg) top left no-repeat, url(../img/ad-takeoverbkg-right.jpg) top right no-repeat;
```

And this worked fine However I now need to dynamically deliver the URL values via JavaScript. The values are retrieved from a JSON array using AJAX. The code I currently have is:

```
$('body').css({
'background-image' : 'url(' + data.leftWpTakeover + ')',
'background-position' : 'top left',
'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
'background-image' : 'url(' + data.rightWpTakeover + ')',
'background-position' : 'top right',
'background-repeat': 'no-repeat'
});
```

This works but the second image replaces the first leaving only the second image added. I need the code to add both background images to the body tag. Can you please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple images to the background by listing them with a comma between them like this:

```
'background-image' : 'url(' + data.leftWpTakeover + '), url(' + data.rightWpTakeover + ')'
```

Comment: Hi Kaloyan. Thanks for the reponse but how do I then add the additional elements? I need image 1 to be "top left no-repeat" and image 2 to be "top right no-repeat". When I try and add those in it fails.

Comment: I got this working by adding separate $("body").css calls for each additional attribute. Feels clunky but it's working so thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. I was happy to help.